# Tailwind CSS - Creating a Kanban board

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a kanban board with tailwind css.
but I'm facing an issue when there are a lot of items in a list.

the list height grows and I'm not able to scroll. because I've added `overflow-y-hidden` to the container.

the max height of the list should not be greater the container and if there are more items I want to show a scroll bar instead.

How can I achieve this?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div
  class="absolute top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex items-start pb-16 overflow-x-auto overflow-y-hidden select-none "
>
  <!-- List Start -->
  <div class="mx-1 bg-white border rounded-lg" style="min-width: 260px">
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-3 space-x-2 border-b">
      <h2 class="text-sm font-medium uppercase">Approved</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Header End -->

    <!-- Items Start -->
    <div
      class="relative flex flex-col h-full px-4 py-4 space-y-3 overflow-auto bg-white "
      style="background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%"
    >
      <div
        class="flex items-center w-full px-1 text-sm border rounded-lg shadow-sm cursor-pointer select-none  group"
        style="background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%"
      >
        <button type="button" class="inline-block w-full py-2 text-left">
          Create email templates for BPM
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Items End -->

    <!-- Add New Start -->
    <div class="flex items-center px-4 pb-4">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="flex items-center px-2 py-1 space-x-2 text-gray-700 rounded-md  hover:bg-gray-100"
      >
        <span>Add New</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Add New End -->
  </div>
  <!-- List End -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**From the tailwind docs**:

Use overflow-auto to add scrollbars to an element in the event that its content overflows the bounds of that element. Unlike .overflow-scroll, which always shows scrollbars, this utility will only show them if scrolling is necessary.

```
<div class="overflow-auto h-32 ...">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```